# Invalid argument: name - unknown error

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, syntax, formatting

this is my first proper script on Google Scripts and I was going well until I hit a shortfall and ran into this error...!

```
Invalid argument: name (line 314, file "main", project "WallFeed")
```

Basically I have no idea what the error is as apparently its the following line which is highlighted as the error:

```
  var LogSS = SpreadsheetApp.create(conf("LogNAME", null, null))
```

It seems like some kind of script formatting error in some regards but others not.

When I stop calling the function with the error its fine

Putting the whole code through a Javascript syntax checked - nothing

Anyone seen this before?

**Calling function**

```
function log(m) {

    LogFID = conf("LogFID", null, null)

    Logger.log("Opening log file: " + LogFID)

    // Try to open the log file
    try {
      log_file = DriveApp.getFileById(LogFID)

      if ( log_file.isTrashed() ) {
        throw new Error("File [" + LogFID + "] has been trashed! Creating a new log file")
      }

    } catch(e) {
      Logger.log(e.message)
      Logger.log(m)

      // Create a new log file
      create_log_file()

      // Log the error and original message
      log(e.message)
      log(m)

      return true
    }

    var lock = LockService.getPublicLock()
    if (lock.tryLock(10000))  {

       var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(LogFID)  
       var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0]

       var newRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1      
       sheet.getRange(newRow, 1).setValue(Date())

       try {
         sheet.getRange(newRow, 2).setValue(m.toString())
       } catch(e) {
         Logger.log("Could not convert log to string: " + e.message)
         Logger.log(m)
         return false
       }

      sheet.autoResizeColumn(1)
      sheet.autoResizeColumn(2)

      lock.releaseLock()

    } else {
      Logger.log("Lock timeout for LogFID: " + LogFID)
      return false
    }

  return true

}
```

**Called function where error occurs**

```
function create_log_file() {

  // Create spreadsheet log file
  var LogSS = SpreadsheetApp.create(conf("LogNAME", null, null))
  LogFID = LogSS.getId()
  conf("LogFID", LogFID, false)

....etc
```

Not too keen to post my full code on here but I can share it with someone if they could take a look?

TIA!!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this this is a deep Google Scripting error... I *had* two Google accounts joined when creating this script which messed things about. Basically I was writing the script in one account and running it another. Strangely things like creating files was ok and they were created in the correct accounts Drive but other things obviously don't work when you have two accounts!

UPDATE: This is actually not the case, the same type of error has raised it's head again, meaning I can't carry on coding...! This time I rolled back to a known good version but the same error was there.